# Fill in missing point in grid

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology

I was doing some destructive work in Blender when it frustratingly crashed on me. I was just testing a few things.

I was trying `"Dissolve vertices"` on my mesh, and ended up with this when I reloaded the project again:

[image]

I tried `F` to join each edge, but it made a strange tugging-looking mesh.

How can I fix this grid mesh, by adding the point in the middle and all the other edges?

Comment: It seems that Grid Fill will do the job, for me it worked with Span = 2, Offset = 1

Comment: Assuming the blank area is a face, select a pair of opposite vertices,  hit 'J', and then do the same with the other pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some modifiers applied to your object, most likely a subdivision surface with the "edit cage to modifier result" option enabled. That's whats causing the tuggy-looking mesh.

Don't worry though, it's not as bad as it seems, it really is just a square hole and is easily fixed.
Simply select the vertices opposite each other (but not alternate corners!) like this:

[image]

and then press <kbd>J</kbd>
This will join the vertices across the face and give you this result:

[image]

Just do the same to the remaining, opposing set of vertices and you're back to a grid!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked perfectly! Instead of `F`, I just needed to do `J` :p

Comment: Well, you still need the face to be present in order for the j operation to work. So F is still good :)

Answer (score 1):

Standard way is to remove tha Ngon face and use *Grid Fill* to fill in with quads. Another a bit less fast way is to use either *Connect Vertex Path* tool (<kbd>J</kbd>) or Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) to cut edges according to existing geometry.

However there might be another way without removing that face:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to poke faces.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads.

[image]

Note that it depends on geometry what resulting topology you will get. Also note - *Grid Fill* restores the curvature of the filled surfaces, this way doesn't.